# what can happen if some thread makes object null and other thread is inside method of that object

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Suppose I have -

```
public class ThreadingIssue {
    public B b = new B();
}

class B{
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void someMethod(int timeOut){
        synchronized(lock){
            try{
                lock.wait(timeOut);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            // some task..
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class Thread1 implements Runnable{
    private ThreadingIssue t;

    public Thread1(ThreadingIssue issue) {
        t = issue;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
              t.b.someMethod(5000);
        }
    }
}

class Thread2 implements Runnable{
    private ThreadingIssue t;

    public Thread2(ThreadingIssue issue){
        t = issue;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        t.b = null;
    }
}
```

what can happen to Thread1, if it is inside `someMethod(5000)` of B and waiting for lock, and Thread2 has made B's object to null? I am unsure whether Thread1 will throw which exception.. any help?

Comment: is that a real problem or you just training your predictionary skill?

Comment: Alex, this is just question, but I am using this concept in big application, so I have not pasted code of application which thousands of line, I have just created question, so.

Comment: You can only null out references to an object; you can't null out the object itself, so there is no problem.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, yep I have made reference null, but both threads are using same reference. Reference is shared between two. I mean both will be pointing to same address stored in heap. But I got result is - after making t.b to null, any thread if calls that method, it will get NPE. And it helped me to avoid test condition for checking whether my implemented Socket is closed, million times in second? As I am sending millions packets in second, without testing sockets is closed before sending next packet. If socket is closed by some thread, packet sender thread will get NPE.. :) :D :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising SJuan76 and the op's discussion:
Looks like there are two references to t, but only one to b (the one inside t).
t will not get released, because the threads hold it independently. However, b may be deleted (depending on gc) because its ref count will drop to zero once the reference is nullified.
So Thread2 may throw a NullPointerException.

Edit:
Inside someMethod(), the b object will not be freed, because the `this` pointer is held on the stack, making the ref count 1, at least. You can say the same thing for every execution of a member method since every one of them get `this` as an argument.

Please note that although you get a NullPointerException, it doesn't mean the object is finalized/freed already, just that the reference you are using is null. The GC may take some time to actually free the object.

Comment: Correct Oren, there is only one reference to b through t, so I was unclear about result. What I did in Thread1 is - public void run(){          while(true){     t.b.someMethod(5000);   }     } so after Thread1 completes method and call it second time, it thrown NPE exception. And that helped me to avoid test if conditions million times per second.

Comment: "However, b may be deleted (depending on gc) because its ref count will drop to zero once the reference is nullified."  - So waht can happen to Thread1 which is inside method of that object? I have tested and Thread1 worked perfectly, but Thread1 got NPE in second call. Is it like result will be unpredictable?

Comment: @johndoe: Edited the original answer to include answers for your questions.

Comment: Thanks @Oren S, now everything is clear. Clear answer. AWESOME Edit. Thanks a lot. This is fundamental question but tricky one. :D

Answer (score 3):

The second thread holds a reference to the object whose method it is running (otherwise it would not be able to run its instance methods), so the GC cannot dispose of the object so there is no possibility of Exception.

To be more explicit with your code, when you do

```
t.b.someMethod(5000)
```

internally the JVM process the `t.b` expression (which is a reference to the object), so the reference count is not 0.

Comment: SJuan, I am unsure if it is true, because both threads uses same instance t.b. And one thread has made this to null, which other thread is still accessing. Is it like when other thread completes method, after that null will be assigned to t.b?

Comment: Test it. After nullifying the vale, start calling `System.gc()` every few seconds. And you can change the strategy for GC by passing a system property (I do not recall which) so it cleans as many objects as possible.

Comment: Got it, thanks SJuan.. I tested making it 

        while(true){

            t.b.someMethod(5000);

        }

and got null pointer exception in second call, which I need..

Comment: So this answer is wrong, isn't it? @SJuan76, can you edit it to avoid misleading people who don't read the comments?